# How to check whether a string is null or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could any one give me an idea to check whether a string is `null` or not without making use of followin:

```
1. length(string)
2. Comparing string with ""
3. string ! = NULL
```

Comment: you can check weather on different sites like weather.yahoo.com or accuweather.com :) try ISNULL(string)

Comment: keymone, it's fixed already! Pearl: remember this: The farmer wondered whether the adverse weather had affected his wether. :-) (A wether is a castrated male sheep.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `IS NOT NULL` on String

Like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE someString IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: can i make use in if statement like declare @str varchar(20) set @str =" " if(@str is not null) 
print 'not null' else print 'null'

Comment: I am not sure where are you leading me to. If you assign a value `' '` to a variable then it will not be `NULL`.

Comment: yes :-) I got it.Space is not considered as null right.
Thank you:-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `string IS NOT NULL`. Using `string != NULL` is not valid SQL...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your asking, but you can check for null using IS NULL;

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '' IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NULL IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN NULLIF(some_text, '') IS NULL THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END
```